# Can we add a turning penalty in Dijkstra's algorithm

Tags: dijkstra

I am trying to code Dijkstra algorithm to find the shortest paths between nodes of some electrical cable trays (given as directed graph). My question is; if we have turns (i.e. not a straight path as the company wish to have) how we can handle this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Dijkstra cannot incorporate a turn-penalty directly, since it is built around the assumption that the cost to reach a node is independent of its "context".

It is possible to rewrite your graph so that every turn is associated with taking an edge, so turn costs become normal costs. Dijkstra can then be applied to that graph. A full explanation can be found in "Modeling Costs of Turns in Route Planning" (Stephan Winter). The graph used for this (line graph) is sometimes called the dual graph, though that term traditionally had a different meaning. Roughly, you introduce a node for every original edge, and an edge between two of the new nodes if the corresponding edges are both adjacent to the same original node (every tiny path of 2 steps is represented by an edge in the new graph). All edges leading out of the source and into the target correspond to separate nodes in the new graph, to avoid turning the problem into multi-source/multi-target shortest path, you may add an additional source node and target node that "tie the edges together" (with zero cost).

Comment: Thanks. would you think A* will handle the problem then instead of implementing two algorithms ?

Comment: @user291864 A* can also be applied to that line graph (and cannot directly incorporate turn costs, for the same reason that Dijkstra cannot), I'm not sure how to do the heuristic but it can be set to zero

Answer (score 0):

When exploring a new neighbor, if this exploration requires a turn, do not explore this neighbor. Make the turn, push this state into the queue and skip this iteration of the loop (e.g. using `continue` in Python).

The reason is this would be 2 actions: moving along an edge and making a turn.

Here is an example where Dijkstra's algorithm failed to find the optimal path when considering turn penalties:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A transportation paper adapted the shortest path algorithm to consider the turning penalty, basically by keeping track of the next node to go and adding in the turn penalty in advance:
Ziliaskopoulos, A.K., Mahmassani, H.S., 1996. A note on least time path computation considering delays and prohibitions for intersection movements. Transportation Research Part B: Methodological 30, 359–367. https://doi.org/10.1016/0191-2615(96)00001-X

This avoids exploding each node for turn movement which would result in a much bigger network.

I have implemented this by adapting the Dijkstra in the NetworkX package:
https://github.com/maxtmng/shortest_path_turn_penalty/